# "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!" error while creating a new Store Instruction

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am trying to create a new `Store` instruction using the following code:

```
AllocaInst* newTemp = new AllocaInst(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 0, 4,tVname);
bb->getInstList().insert(original, newTemp);
Value* dest = inst->getOperand(1);
StoreInst *strTwo = new StoreInst(newTemp, dest,0,4); //newTemp creates error
bb->getInstList().insert(bfrInst, strTwo);
```

When I run the code, it throws the exception:

`void llvm::StoreInst::AssertOK(): Assertion getOperand(0)->getType() == cast<PointerType>(getOperand(1)->getType())->getElementType() && "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!"' failed.`

How should I modify the code to make error free ?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi It is an `add` instruction. I am fetching its second operand.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StoreInst.html

StoreInst takes first argument value and second as pointer.
Seems like you are doing it in reverse

```
 StoreInst *strTwo = new StoreInst(newTemp, dest,0,4); //newTemp creates error
```

If you are trying to store dest to newtemp alloca pointer try:

```
 StoreInst *strTwo = new StoreInst(dest, newtemp,0,4); //newTemp creates error
```